# Request is nil and cookies are empty after Stripe redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, cookies, request, stripe-payments

I'm sure I'm missing something very basic here. When a user wants to authenticate with Stripe, they're redirected to Stripe's website, where they grant permission to my website, and then redirected back to my website. When they reach my website, they're suddenly not recognized, because their cookies from my site are empty, and actually `request` is nil. Due to the resultant errors, they're redirected back to my home page, where the cookies and `request` are back, and they're logged in like normal.

Why is everything blank in the redirect path?

**Update: Solved, but I'm not sure how**

Still not sure what the issue was, but I just changed the route name from `/user/afterstripe` with `www` as the subdomain, to `/connect/afterstripe` with `user` as the subdomain, and now my cookies and `request` object are there. My cookies do work on other paths that use the `www` subdomain.

Comment: This really depends on your web framework. Are you missing some middleware on the `return_url` route which deal with sessions? Try accessing it directly after you login and see if you are seeing the same issue?

Comment: @wsw Trying to access it directly really should've been the first thing I did - it really didn't have anything to do with Stripe. I still don't know what the issue was and don't have time to dig into it, but I literally just changed the route name (including the subdomain) and now it works...